# Parallel execution with Serenity and JBehave?

Tags: maven, jbehave, serenity-bdd

How to execute parallel Serenity + JBehave + Maven tests? 
I tried with settings:
serenity.batch.size = 3
serenity.batch.count = 2

but tests are still not executed in parallel.

My AcceptanceTestSute:

```java
public class AcceptanceTestSuite extends SerenityStories {

    private static final String STORY_FILE_NAME = "story.file.name";

    public AcceptanceTestSuite() {
        super();
        Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(STORY_FILE_NAME)).ifPresent(this::findStoriesCalled);
        configuration().useParameterControls(new ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(true));
        configuration().usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep());
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off-topic. Please change your question to be more specific.

Comment: I thought any example how to set parallel execution with Serenity + JBehave. I found some examples but most of them for Serenity + Junit.

Comment: Then we need to close the question because it is off-topic.

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Are you using page objects?  Have your page object elements and methods been defined as static?  Chances are your problems have nothing to do with JBehave or Serenity.  Parallel testing is a complex subject all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The batch size and batch count parameters are for running batches across multiple machines, not for running tests in parallel on a single machine, and in any case do not work with JBehave. The best strategy is to create a separate runner class for each of your story files and use Maven or Gradle to run the runner classes in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for reply John. We are starting new project and I am thinking about using serenity framework. I am wondering, if I choose Cucumber instead of JBehave, would be easier to set up parallel execution?

Comment: It would only be easier in the sense that Cucumber more readily interfaces with TestNG.  JBehave might, but I've only ever used it with JUnit.  TestNG makes writing parallel tests much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it as John Smart advised, using separate runner classes. Thanks.